# An Invalid SQL statement was used with SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, file-geodatabase, runtimeerror

The code:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive - xxxx\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\xxxx_Test\FinalUnions_VTDs.gdb\New_Final_VTD_SplitLayer'


prevFieldValueList = []
counter = 1

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("Split Name Seq")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0])
        if row[0] in prevFieldValueList:
            counter += 1
            print(counter)
            print('if block')
        else:
            counter = 1
            print(counter)
            print('else block')
        prevFieldValue = row[0]
        prevFieldValueList.append(prevFieldValue)
```

It's a very simple codeblock to update precinct names. However, I want to be able to show my colleague how this script is stepping through each attribute within the field and assigning the correct name.

However, this is the error I get when I run the script:

```
  File "C:/PA_Boundaries/Precinct_Naming.py", line 10, in <module>
    for row in cursor:

RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT OBJECTID,Split Name Seq FROM New_Final_VTD_SplitLayer]
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I have used Cursors in abundance in the past with more complex tools, and have never had this issue.

Comment: "Split Name Seq" is not a valid column name. Did you mean `['Split','Name','Seq']`?

Comment: 'Split Name Seq' is the name of my column in the featureclass. Are you saying that the Cursor cannot interpret this name correctly even though that is the correct name of the field?

Comment: That's not the field name. That's an *alias* (for display purposes). The actual field name is not permitted spaces. Cursors require field names.

Comment: The parameter is a list, so a tuple is okay. Putting double-quotes around the alias might help e.g., ('"Split Name Seq"')

Comment: If you open the attribute table, there should be an option in the menu, something like 'show field alias' - uncheck that and you should see the actual field names.  Use the actual field name, like Vince suggested.

Comment: Do you use ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?  The exact nature of how to see the real column name (instead of the alias) differs.  Also, the 'ListFields' command in arcpy to list all the (real) field names is different between the two.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses everyone. Got it to step through thanks to Vince. Problem solved!